# Returning references to dynamically allocated objects

Tags: c++, reference, return

I have the following example to illustrate my question.
I have the class Matrix

```
class Matrix{


   private:

      int *array;
      int x;
      int y;

   public:

      //some other things..
      Matrix& operator+(Matrix& add);
      Matrix& operator=(Matrix& matr);

}
```

I want the operator + to return a completely new object which will be assigned to Matrix objects, not references to Matrix nor pointers to Matrix.
So the operator = will have just to copy the values bit by bit.

(I know that this implementation of Matrix class is not good but i make it like this to illustrate my problem)

Now the problem is the implementation of operator +

First i tried to create an object in the overloaded function like this

```
Matrix sum;
//do what i have to do and then
return sum;
```

but this brings problems as the object sum will of course be destroyed and the destructor of Matrix will of course

```
 delete [] array;
```

The alternative is to create

```
Matrix *sum;

sum = new Matrix;

sum->array = new int[//size that i need];
//do what i have to do

return *sum;
```

So now in the main

```
C=A+B;
```

(A,B,C are matrix objects)

A+B returns a newly created reference to an object in the heap.
This object will be assigned to C and a copy bit by bit will occur.C will have the correct x value ,correct y value and C->array will point to the int array that had been allocated in the overloaded operator+

Finally after this assigment i will have a memory leak it will be the **(sizeof(Matrix))** bytes that were allocated at the operator+ function at the line

```
sum = new Matrix;
```

So i want an answer that indicates how i can avoid the memory leak in the second case.

I repeat that the implementation is not good but i made it just to show the problem that i have.
Also i could have had only pointers to Matrix in main and make all the Matrix functions return Matrix pointers.This would solve many problems but i want a solution to this specific case.

Comment: `operator+` should return a new object, not a reference.

Answer (score 3):

A proper prototype for `operator+` is

```
Matrix operator+(Matrix add);
```

and is, if available, implemented using `operator+=`:

```
{
   add += *this;  //or just the logic if += isn't implemented
   return add;
}
```

Note that `add` is passed by value because you're modifying it anyway (as opposed to creating a new `Matrix`) - this leaves room for optimizations.

The alternative free function would be:

```
 Matrix operator+ (Matrix mat1, const Matrix& mat2)
 {
     mat1 += mat2;
     return mat1;
 }
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference between your free function and your member function. In this case, addition can probably assumed to be commutative, but this doesn't need hold in the general case (so you might have to actually pass `add` by reference and copy `*this` to get the operand-order right).

Answer (score 1):

operator + should return Matrix, not Matrix&. Just forget the latter.

See item 21 In Effective C++ by Scott Meyers for details.

[A fraction here](http://www.ycshao.com/?p=599)